# $\mathbb{E}(Y\circ X)= \mathbb{E}(Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable from a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ to a measurable space $(\Psi, \mathcal{G})$. Let $Q$ denote the probability measure on $(\Psi, \mathcal{G})$ induced by $X$ and let $Y$ be an $\bar{\mathbb{R}}-$valued random variable on $(\Psi, \mathcal{G}, Q)$. Then $\mathbb{E}_P(Y\circ X)= \mathbb{E}_Q(Y)$

I´m trying to use the Monotone class theorem on $Y$, but I´m stuck.

The theorem says that the smallest monotone class containing an algebra of sets G is precisely the smallest σ-algebra containing G, and a monotone class is a collection $M$ of sets which is closed under countable monotone unions and intersections.

Comment: at which point are you stuck?

Comment: trying to apply the theorem, I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may show this directly by approximating $Y$ with simple functions. Namely, the result is true for the indicators of sets in $\mathcal{G}$ (*by the definition of the image measure*) and, hence, it is true for simple functions. Then, using the Monotone Convergence Theorem, the equality holds for all nonnegative functions (*approximate such $Y\ge 0$ by an increasing sequence of simple functions*). Finally, since $(Y\circ X)_{+}=Y_{+}\circ X$ and $(Y\circ X)_{-}=Y_{-}\circ X$, the result is extended to all functions for which both expectations are defined.

Comment: I think it is more complicated than I thought hehehe I´m trying to prove that the set $M$ is monotone but how the expected values is closed under intersection and unions..

Comment: What do you mean by "expected values is closed under intersection and unions"?

Comment: $M := \{G \in \mathcal{G}: \mathbb{E}_{P}[1_{G} \circ X] = \mathbb{E}_{Q}[1_G]\}$ is a monotone class, I´m trying to prove that.

Comment: Oh. you mean "under increasing unions and decreasing intersections". Use the continuity of measures/bounded convergence theorem...

Comment: yea sorry for not to be specific hehe, yea yea my teacher told that use that just I get a mess in my problem hehee

Comment: For example, if $G_1\subset G_2\subset G_3\dots$, then
$$
\mathsf{E}1_{\bigcup G_i}=Q\left(\bigcup G_i\right)=\lim Q(G_i).
$$

Answer (score 1):

First show that $M := \{G \in \mathcal{G}: \mathbb{E}_{P}[1_{G} \circ X] = \mathbb{E}_{Q}[1_G]\}$ is a monotone class. Then consider a sequence of simple functions $t_n$ such that $t_n \nearrow Y$ monotonically.

Comment: but the Expected value is not closed under intersection? how do you know M is monotone class?